# Not able to pass dynamic header values using xslt

Tags: xslt

I am trying to convert JSON message in to XML using xslt,I am passing Header and body as Json message from SOAPUI,I want to read the header values from incoming header and update it in static header which is placed in XSLT.Also We want to remove the json header which is comming in incoming message and pass it service.

Please find the below JSON message, XSLT and expected output, could you please help us here

JSON Message :

```json
{"soapenv:Header": {
      "head:Header": {
        "head:Version": "1.0",
        "head:ConversationUID": "test",
        "head:MessageUID": "test1",
            }
            },
    "soapenv:Body": {
      "act:ABC_request": {
        "act:PolNumber": "123",
        "act:SubDivisionID": "ABC",
        "act:SubDivisionQualifierType": "ABC",
        "act:SubDivisionQualifier": "100",
        "act:SearchIndex": "0",
        "act:MaximumCount": "200"
      }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Where are the XSLT and the expected output? Thank you.

Comment: "I am trying to convert JSON message in to XML using xslt," - this is not possible with XSLT. XSLT transforms XML *into* other things. It does not transform other things into XML. Some XSLT processors can be extended with custom functionality, but actually you should look for are different solution that can convert JSON to XML. These solutions exist, pick one.